# sort list elements in python in ascending order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list of elements and I have to perform sorting in acceding order.

Below is the list1.  consider after colon value ( if element is 'abcd_z12_yyy:3590,60240,0', ordering participant is 3590) for ascending ordering.

```
>> list1 = ['abcd_z05_yyy:2182,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z06_yyy:2566,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z07_yyy:618,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z08_yyy:6,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z09_yyy:8838,60240,2',
...  'abcd_z10_yyy:6534,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z11_yyy:1680,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z12_yyy:3590,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z13_yyy:6,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z14_yyy:6,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z15_yyy:6,60240,0',
...  'abcd_z16_yyy:6,60240,0']

>>> sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x.split(':')[1])
```

Output:

```
['abcd_z11_yyy:1680,60240,0', 'abcd_z05_yyy:2182,60240,0', 'abcd_z06_yyy:2566,60240,0', 'abcd_z12_yyy:3590,60240,0', 'abcd_z08_yyy:6,60240,0', 'abcd_z13_yyy:6,60240,0', 'abcd_z14_yyy:6,60240,0', 'abcd_z15_yyy:6,60240,0', 'abcd_z16_yyy:6,60240,0', 'abcd_z07_yyy:618,60240,0', 'abcd_z10_yyy:6534,60240,0', 'abcd_z09_yyy:8838,60240,2']
>>>
```

Expected output:

```
 ['abcd_z08_yyy:6,60240,0',
  'abcd_z13_yyy:6,60240,0',
  'abcd_z14_yyy:6,60240,0',
  'abcd_z15_yyy:6,60240,0',
  'abcd_z16_yyy:6,60240,0',
  'abcd_z07_yyy:618,60240,0',
  'abcd_z11_yyy:1680,60240,0',
  'abcd_z06_yyy:2566,60240,0',
  'abcd_z12_yyy:3590,60240,0',
  'abcd_z10_yyy:6534,60240,0',
  'abcd_z09_yyy:8838,60240,2',
 ]
```

Comment: try `sorted(list1, key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[1].split(',')[0]))`

Comment: @shahaf, It worked. Thanks :)